# How to move an object through the scene tree in Godot?

Tags: godot, godot4, godot-shader-language

I created an Area2D node and created an AnimatedSprite node in it.
I select a random sprite and create it with the Add_child function, I scroll with the script, but the scrollable background appears in the foreground and closes the "player"

tried to find functions in documentation, video on youtube (didn't find/doesn't work)
I also tried to change the node to parallax, but as I understand it, you can’t use different sprites in it

Answer (score 1):

do I get the question right: so the background is drawn over the sprites? than it is just a matter of re-aranging your nodes in the corrosponding tree.
Basically thing get drawn from Top to Bottom like they appear in the Node Tree